# My Home Folder opens in Sublime Text

Tags: 14.10, mate

I'm using a fresh **Ubuntu Mate** 14.10 install.

I installed Sublime Text 2 and now when I go to Places -> Home Folder/Desktop, it opens in Sublime Text instead of Caja.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Running this in the terminal fixed the problem:

```
$ xdg-mime default caja.desktop inode/directory
```

Comment: You can also change it by editing the file **/etc/gnome/defaults.list** and modifying **inode/directory** with wanted one.